# Create catalogue like serial number with reference text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create some kind of item catalogue number with empty boxes/spaces instead of some selected characters and draw perpendicular lines to these empty places and "tag" them. Example picture below:
 [image: example picture]

EDIT: to rephrase. I can do something like this:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,-1) [label=left:tag1](t1){};
\node at (1,0)  [label=EXAMPLE\slash](){};
\node at (2,0)  [label=\fbox{\phantom{X}}](t2){};

\draw
    (t1) -| (t2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But I don't know the way to make multiple nodes like this so they look like a part of one string.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `chains` library can be helpful here, for automating placement:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[
  node distance=1mm,
  start chain=place,
  every node/.style={
    on chain,
    font=\strut,
    path picture={
       \draw (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.south east);
    }
  }
]
\node {foo};
\node {bar};
\node {baz};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[
  node distance=2mm,
  start chain=tag going below,
  every node/.style={on chain}
]
\node at (-2,-0.5) {Tag1};
\node {Tag2};
\node {Tag3};
\end{scope}

\foreach \i in {1,...,3}
  \draw (tag-\i) -| (place-\i);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```